# MPI 2x printing

Tags: c, parallel-processing, printf, mpi

I'm studying a bit of MPI, and decided to do a test by making a program that calls objects, eg `main.c` -> main program, `function.c` -> any function

function.c that will only use the MPI. compiling I as follows:

```
gcc-c main.c
```

to create `main.o`, `mpicc-c` to create `function.c` `function.o`, of course I create the file `function.h` too.

I compile with `mpicc-o` program `main.o` `function.o`

Here is `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "function.h"

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Hello\n");
  function();
  printf("Bye\n");
}
```

just function has the MPI code, but when I'm running the program `mpiexe -np 2` I get

```
Hello
Hello
----- function job here -----
Bye
Bye
```

But I wanted it to be

```
Hello
------ function job -----
Bye
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole program is run on both of the two processors you set with the `-np 2`. A common way to prevent duplicates of printouts, final results, etc., is have one thread do those things just by checking the thread id first. Like:

```
int id;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
if (id == 0) {
  printf("only process %d does this one\n", id);
}

printf("hello from process %d\n", id);  // all processes do this one
```

When starting out in MPI I found it helpful to print out those id numbers along with whatever partial results or data each thread was dealing with. Helped me make more sense out of what was happening.

Comment: so, in every routine i must use MPI_Comm_rank and print in only 1 rank, but i need call MPI_Init in every routine too?

Comment: you shouldn't need to call MPI_Init in outside functions--just in your `main`

Answer (score 0):

Basically `mpirun -np 2` starts 2 identical processes and you have to use `MPI_Comm_rank` function to check process rank.

Here is a quick snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int myrank;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
  if (myrank == 0) {
    printf("Hello\n");
    function();
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Done\n");
  } else {
    function();
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer this method for printing data.
It involves barriers. So you must be careful while using it.

```
if(1)
do
  for(i = 0 to num_threads)
  do
     if(i==my_rank)
     do
       do_printf
     done

      ******* barrier ********
  end for
done
```

If the set of threads printing the value does not include all threads, just add the relevant threads to barrier.

Another method is for every thread to write its output in a dedicated file. This way  :

1. you don't have to access a barrier
2. you do not lose printfs of any thread
3. you output is explicit. so there is no cluttering while debugging programs.

Code :

```
sprintf(my_op_file_str, "output%d", myThreadID);
close(1)
open(my_op_file_str)

Now use printf's anywhere you may like.
```